# Sobolev space is spanned by distributions supported on half-lines?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512734/sobolev-space-is-spanned-by-distributions-supported-on-half-lines?noredirect=1#comment9476326_4512734) on Mathematics Stack Exchange previously.
This seems to be a very basic property of Sobolev spaces, but I wasn't able to find a proof for it.

> For any $s \leq 1/2$,
> $$H^s(\mathbb{R}) = H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$$
> where $H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) = \{ u \in H^s(\mathbb{R}) \mid \operatorname{supp} u \subset (-\infty, 0] \}$ and $H^s_+(\mathbb{R}) = \{ u \in H^s(\mathbb{R}) \mid \operatorname{supp} u \subset [0, \infty) \}$.

I am only really interested in the case $s < 1/2$, but I am led to believe the result also holds for $s = 1/2$.

**Context**

This question stems from my attempt to prove subjectivity of the natural map
$$H^s_+(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^s([0, \infty)) = H^s(\mathbb{R}) / H^s_-(\mathbb{R})$$
and its higher dimensional analogues $H^s_+(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow H^s([0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^d)$.
This property is claimed in Melrose's [notes](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erbm/daomwc3.ps), Proposition 3.5.1.
The proof involves taking the dual of the injection
$H^{-s}_+(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^{-s}([0,\infty))$.
But this requires the natural topology of $H^{-s}_+(\mathbb{R})$ to coincide with the subspace topology from $H^{-s}([0,\infty))$, which is not justified in the notes.
I believe the latter property is equivalent to $H^{-s}_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^{-s}_+(\mathbb{R})$ being closed in $H^{-s}(\mathbb{R})$.

**My thoughts**

In the case $s < 1/2$, I can show that $H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$ contains the Schwartz functions $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, but this does not imply the desired result unless $H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$ is closed.

The inclusion $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \subset H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$ is obtained by multiplying $u \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ by sequences of smooth functions approximating the indicators on $(-\infty, 0]$ and $[0, \infty)$, and showing that the resulting sequences converge in $H^s$.
For example, fixing a smooth $\phi$ supported on $[0, \infty)$ and eventually equal to 1, then consider its scalings $\phi_{\epsilon}(x) = \phi(x /\epsilon)$.
One can show that $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} u \phi_{\epsilon}$ converges in $H^s$, $s \in [0, 1/2)$ using the inequality $\|v\|_{H^s} \lesssim \|v\|_{H^0}^{1-s} \|v\|_{H^1}^s$ and the crude estimates
$$\|u(\phi_\epsilon - \phi_\delta)\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{L^{\infty}} \|\phi_\epsilon - \phi_\delta\|_{L^\infty} \|\phi_\epsilon - \phi_\delta\|_{L^0}^{1/2} \lesssim \epsilon^{1/2}$$
$$\|u \cdot \partial(\phi_\epsilon - \phi_\delta)\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{L^\infty} \|\partial(\phi_\epsilon - \phi_\delta)\|_{L^\infty} \|\partial(\phi_\epsilon - \phi_\delta)\|_{L^0}^{1/2} \lesssim \epsilon^{-1} \epsilon^{1/2}$$
I am unable to generalize this to the case $u \in H^s$ or $s = 1/2$.
Any suggestion or reference is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since everything is a function, the only way to obtain such a decomposition $u=u_++u_-$ is the obvious one, by restricting to the half lines. But this is the same as applying (something like) $1\pm H$ to $\widehat{u}$, $H$ denoting the Hilbert transform. So your question is closely related to this one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378388/hilbert-transform-on-weighted-sobolev-spaces

Comment: A related question is whether $H^s_- + H^s_+$ is closed in $H^s$. This is equivalent to these closed subspaces (quotient by intersect) having a positive gap. In the case $s > -1/2$, another equivalent statement is $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ and $H^s([0,\infty))$ induce the same topology on $H^s_+$. If they do, then $H^s_+$ can be taken as an alternative definition of $H^s_0([0,\infty))$. In view of Prof. Remling's answer and $H^{1/2}_0([0,\infty)) = H^{1/2}([0,\infty))$, I suspect that $H^{1/2}_+ \neq H^{1/2}_0([0,\infty))$.

Comment: It just occurred to me writing the previous comment that this is related to the question of zero-extension for members of $H^{s}_0$.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as explained in my comment, this is the same as asking if the Hilbert transform is bounded on $L^2(\mathbb R, w\, dx)$, with $w(x)=(1+|x|)^{2s}$. Or, to state this one more time, this reformulation follows because restricting $u$ to a half line is essentially the same as applying the Hilbert transform to $\widehat{u}$. Hunt, Muckenhoupt, Wheeden [proved](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-176-00/S0002-9947-1973-0312139-8/S0002-9947-1973-0312139-8.pdf) that this is equivalent to $w\in A_2$ (see Theorem 9 there).

It is easy to check, using the defining condition
$$
\int_I w \int_I w^{-1}\lesssim |I|^2
$$
of $A_2$, that indeed $w\in A_2$ for our weight $w(x)=(1+|x|)^{2s}$ as long as $-1/2<s<1/2$.

If $s=1/2$, then in fact $w(x)=1+|x|\notin A_2$, so the argument shows that $u\in H^{1/2}$ does not in general admit a $u=u_++u_-$ decomposition. Thank you to Giorgio for pointing this out, and I hope no one read the rather nonsensical comment I made here originally.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Remling. This is a useful characterization. However, I am guessing from symmetry that the Hilbert transform is only bounded for $w$ between $\langle x \rangle^{-1/2}$ and $\langle x \rangle^{1/2}$. So this method would only cover the case $s \in [-1/2,1/2]$. Do you have any idea about $s < -1/2$? In that case, the decomposition is no longer unique. Also, I am wondering whether there is simple proof that cover both cases, possibly ignoring $s=1/2$. It seems a pity that such an essential and elementary fact requires so much analysis to justify.

Comment: @TianXia: Actually, the argument only covers $-1/2<s<1/2$, I made a trivial (but rather confusing to me, for a while, until I finally cleared it up) mistake in the bookkeeping, now corrected.

Comment: @TianXia: Searching for an easier argument (for $s<1/2$ at least), somehow it is tempting to think that the key fact then should be that $\chi_I\in H^s$ then, so the discontinuity perhaps introduced by restricting $u$ to half lines doesn't defeat us immediately. I don't see how to make a proof out of this though.

Comment: @ChristianRemling If $s=1/2$ the weight $(1+|x|)^{2s}$ is not in $A_2$, so your argument should give that the result does not hold. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I guess it is possible the result doesn't hold in the case $s=1/2$. That seems to suggest that $H^{1/2}_+$ does not coincide with $H^{1/2}_{0}$, the closure of compactly supported smooth functions in $H^{1/2}([0,\infty))$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: As far as I'm concerned, that sounds plausible. It even agrees with my naive intuition suggested above that the key fact should be whether or not step functions are in $H^s$ (they are not in $H^{1/2}$).

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: In fact, it's perfectly obvious. If $u=1$ near $x=0$ (and $u\in C_0^{\infty}$, let's say), then the half line restrictions are not in $H^{1/2}$ (their FTs behave like those of $\chi_I$).

Comment: @ChristianRemling True but another thing is maybe worth noticing: $H^s_-+H^s_+$ is dense in $H_s$ also for $s=1/2$. Take $u$ in the Schwartz class and $u_\epsilon=u\phi(x/\epsilon)$ where $\phi$ is even and equal to 0/1 for small/large  $|x|$. Then,  as in the OP text, $\|u_\epsilon -u\|_{H^{1/2}} \leq C$ and, by weak compactness,$u_\epsilon \to u$ weakly. This does not work on one side only, I mean if $\phi $ is the same for positive $x$ and zero for negative beacuse we need $u_\epsilon-u$ small.